# Reference to cocoapods when running unit tests

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, linker, cocoapods

I've created a brand new static library project for iOS in Xcode 5 called 'MyApi'. After that I create a Podfile adding AFNetworking as a dependency so far so good. Lets say that I need to use AFNetworking in my MyApi.h file, #import . Finally I want to run tests on my code. I start by adding #import "MyApi.h" in my MyApiTests.m. If I hit CMD+U to test my code it will complain that the tests can't find AFNetworking. I can solve this by adding link_with "MyApi", "MyApiTests" in my Podfile. But now when I hit Test it will complain about duplicate symbol _OBJC...... (on all AFNetworking classes). I managed to get around this by removing libPods.a in Link Binary With Libraries in the MyApiTests target and everything works fine. But every time I run pod install I will have to do this manual step of removing the libPods.a. Since we don't keep the workspace that cocoa pods creates in our git repo. And since this is running on a jenkins server automatically I can't manually remove the libPods.a file. Can this be done in a better way that works without the manual step?

(Please don't make this a discussion about if you should checkin the xcworkspace).

Comment: in your podfile, is AFNetworking added under your test target?